NGINX: map $request_body
I have $request_body with some string like: auth.user=AABBCC&auth.id=DDFFGG&cmd=login&return_to=site.com&id.required=
I need to write log only with user name from this string (in example this is AABBCC), except auth.user= and first &
How should I map $request_body in Nginx conf?
I tried some examples from Internet, but no luck. I really newbie in Nginx and regular variables not so easy for me to understand.
